# Can't turn off/suspend/logout in intel Mode nvidia prime?

Tags: drivers, 16.04, nvidia, suspend, shutdown

When I am using Nvidia graphics card from prime profile , everything works fine. But when I switch to intel graphics card , suddenly I can't do anything from suspend,logout,shutdown,restart. When I try to do one of these it just hangs and I have to manually hold the power button to shutdown.Everything else is fine.

This is my grub parameters.

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi_osi= acpi_backlight=native"`

My laptop is Asus GL552VW , Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Having the same issue as you. Did you manage to resolve it?